# gspread or such: help me get cell coordinates (not value)

Tags: python-2.7, cell, google-sheets, gspread

By using GSpread I have a range of cell's returned from a google spreadsheet that has all its elements something like this:

```
<Cell R1C1 'Sandero'>
```

I know how to get from here the cell value:

```
cell.value
```

but I would also like to get the address (R1C1 in this case) separately. 
It would have to be (R1,C1) or even better if I can get it in (1,1) format (maybe by using a dictionary?)

You see I need the address as well because I will later declare a graph with these values.

I'm using Python 2.7 and latest Gspread library.

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to get a cell's coordinates is by using the cell's instance properties `row` and `col`. This way your code can be simplified to this:

```
for cell in cell_list:
    print cell.value
    print "Row:", cell.row, "Column:", cell.col
```

To get a tuple, just wrap it in parenthesis: `(cell.row, cell.col)`.

Since I'm the author of gspread, I've updated the [library page](https://github.com/burnash/gspread#google-spreadsheets-python-api) to make it clear how to get a cell's coords. Thanks for pointing out the missing part.

Comment: It's almost trivial, but is there a utility function to convert a cell_list to the rectangular coordinates in A1 form? EG A1:C3 - I guess it's possible a cell list may not be rectangular, but min/max col, min/max row would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours I managed to get the dirty work done by myself.

So I have the data in range of cells obtained from a google spreadsheet already opened:

```
cell_list = worksheet.range('A1:J8')
```

This contains `<Cell R1C1 'Sandero'>` but also `<Cell R1C2 '23'>` and so on.

Now in order to get from the `<Cell R1C1` part the coordinates (1,1) that I would use to create a graph later on in my project I realized the best way is like this:

```
for cell in cell_list: # will check all elements of the worksheet range A1:J8
        print cell # for example at one point this is <Cell R1C1 'Sandero'>
        print cell.value # Sandero
        cella = re.findall(r'\d+',str(cell)) # will take only numbers from <Cell R1C1 'Sandero'>
        print cella[:2] # will give you the first two elements of list cella. 
                         #In this case '1','1'. This is exactly what I need.
      # to specify [:2] it's important if it would be <Cell R1C2 '23'>. 
      # Otherwise cella would return '1','2','23'. Nasty. 
       # I need only coordinates to use them as index in graf.
```

Then have to be careful to refer to my cordinates as `int(cella[0])` and `int(cella[1])` because I had them as strings from `re.findall(r'\d+',str(cell))`

I believe my solution is very messy and overcomplicated but at least it works. I'm still waiting for that stack to overflow so I hope someone has a better idea.