# Can I control the output of insert_row in GSpread?

Tags: python-2.7, google-sheets, gspread

I have successfully imported some data into Gsheets using Gspread(https://github.com/burnash/gspread). However, I see insert_row is getting both the values and the cell details. Can I control it, I want only 'value' to be imported not the cell details?

```
worksheet.insert_row(cell_list, row)
```

`<Cell R1C1 u'this is the value'>, <Cell R1C2 u'this is the value'>, <Cell R1C3 u"this is the value'>`

I looked into some gspread related posts on SO, nothing similar. This post gave me some insight [gspread or such: help me get cell coordinates (not value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949540/gspread-or-such-help-me-get-cell-coordinates-not-value)

update_cells(list) works absolutely fine (updates in a given range) but I cannot insert a new row or a new column. For now, I am using this method (update_cells()) which is getting only values for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works!!

```
objects = Someapi.issues()    
values = []
for issue in objects: #you can change the range here
    values.append(issue.name)
print values #Ignore this statement, Just see what values are printed!!
worksheet.insert_row(values)
```

Somebody helped me. Thanks!!